# Why did God send Dovid to Hebron specifically?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, samuel-shmuel-book-of, king-david, cities

In Shmuel Bet [2:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15862#v=1), Dovid asks God which city he should go to and God tells him to go to Hebron. What is the reason he is told to go to that city specifically? I have seen commentaries explain that it was a big and important city; I'm looking for a conceptual or symbolic reason that it had to be Hebron.

> וַיְהִי אַחֲרֵי כֵן וַיִּשְׁאַל דָּוִד בַּיהֹוָה | לֵאמֹר הַאֶעֱלֶה
>   בְּאַחַת עָרֵי יְהוּדָה וַיֹּאמֶר יְהֹוָה אֵלָיו עֲלֵה וַיֹּאמֶר
>   דָּוִד אָנָה אֶעֱלֶה וַיֹּאמֶר חֶבְרֹנָה
>
> And it was after this, that David enquired of the Lord saying, "Shall
>   I go up into one of the cities of Judah?" And the Lord said to him,
>   "Go up." Said David, "Where shall I go up?" And He said, "To Hebron."

( [*Chabad translation*](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15862#v=1) )

Answer (score 1):

Useruser6641 already mentioned it, but the Zohar offers a mystical explanation as to why G-d said to Dovid that he needed to go to Hebron.

The [Zohar (volume 1, p. 79b)](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.1.79b.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that the reason why G-d tells Avraham "Lech Lecha" - e.g. Go forth from... [(Genesis 12:1)](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.12.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) is to mean that Avraham was not at a certain level yet, to receive G-ds wisdom. That's why G-d told Avraham "go to...", which means reaching a higher level, closer to G-d:

> This is a hint for that place and position that Abraham was expected to reach and that would bring him closer to the Holy One, blessed be He. This is why it is written, "Go for yourself." And that is the first grade that Abraham was to attain in coming to the Holy One, blessed be He.

However, according to the Zohar, the only place where this higher level can be achieved, is within Eretz Yisrael:

> But Abraham could not reach that grade and hold on to it until he entered the land of Yisrael, because that is where this level is achieved.

The same is true with Dovid, says the Zohar:

> It was similar with David, about whom it is written, "David inquired of Hashem, saying, Shall I go up to any of the cities of Yehuda? And Hashem said to him, 'Go up.' And David said, Where shall I go up? And Hashem said, 'to Hevron'" (II Shmuel 2:1). Since Saul had died, and David was fit to receive the kingship, why then did he not receive the kingship over Yisrael immediately?

Dovid was not ready to receive kingship, until he had connected himself to the patriarchs that are buried in Hebron:

> David was not ready to receive the kingship until he had connected himself to the Patriarchs buried in Hebron, through whom he was to receive the kingship. Therefore, he remained in Hevron for seven years, until he was fit to receive the kingship properly.

Maybe another interesting explanation can be found in the sefer called ["מעלין בקודש" , p. 37, it can be found on Otzar HaChochma](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/194765/p/33/t/4038911501234/fs/YMeta5wPGEIG0TuBlKsUp31Lf8iZgvWE5dc63P2ToUXk/start/558/end/612/c):

> מלכות תלויה ברציפות מדור לדור בחברון ניתנה המלכות לאבות ושם הם נקברו על כן על פי הזוהר שבע שנים צריך היה דוד לשהות שם על מנת להתחבר אליהם ולזכות בה אולי מסיבה דומה קדמה חברון ונבחרה לנתינת המלכות לאבות על מנת שיורישוה לבנים שם על פי המסורת קבורים אדם וחוה אדם הראשון שכלל בתוכו

In the sefer "מעלין בקודש" the author explains that the kingship is dependent on the continuity of the generations. The author writes that the kingdom were given to the ancestors, and since they are buried in Hebron, Dovid needed to "connect" to them in order to continue the kingship-line.

This same idea is given in the sefer ["איי הים", p. 41](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/627289/p/41/t/4038911501234/fs/YMeta5wPGEIG0TuBlKsUp31Lf8iZgvWE5dc63P2ToUXk/start/864/end/927/c) starting with the first line "ויאמר ה' אליו עלה ויאמר דזד אנה אעלה":

> ויאמר ה' אליו עלה ויאמר דזד אנה אעלה ויאמר חברנה וכי כיון דמית שאול וכי כיון דמת שאול ומלכותא אתחזי לדוד ודוד היה ראוי לקבל המלכות אמאי לא קביל מלכותא מיד על כל ישראל למה לא קבל מיד את המלכות על כל ישראל אלא כלא רזא דחכמתא אלא הכל סוד החכמה היא איהו בגין דדוד לית ליה לקבלא מלכותא כי דוד לא היה לו לקבל המלכות אלא עד דיתחבר באבהן אלא עד שיתחבר באבות דאינון בחברון שהם בחברון וכדין בהו יקבל מלכותא ואז יקבל מלכות בהם ועל דא אתעכב תמן שבע שנין וע"כ נתעכב שם בחברון שבע שנים בגין דיקבל מלכותא כדקא יאות כדי שיקבל המלכות כראוי וכלא ברזא דחכמתא והכל בסוד החכמה ובגין דיתקן מלכותיה ומשום שיתוקן מלכותו כגוונא דא אברהם לא עאל בקיומא

Answer (score 0):

Hebron is possibly where Jacob was when he selected Judah to be leader. Jacob is clearly shown to be in Hebron in Genesis 37:14. At Hebron, Jacob sends Joseph to see his brothers in Shechem/Dothan. Then his brothers sell him over to the Midianites/Egypt.
When Judah and the brothers show Joseph's bloody coat of colors to Jacob, the first born blessing may have been automatically given to Judah. Since Joseph is no longer supposedly alive to Jacob. And this is possibly done in Hebron, where Jacob is residing at the time of them selling Joseph away.

So, God feels that David needs to pray tribute to his ancestor Judah and be anointed King in Hebron, just like Judah was.  2 Samuel 2:4.

There's a story or two at Hebron in Genesis. But there hasn't really been a story/event in Hebron post-Israelite conquest (after the book of Joshua), until 2 Samuel when God tells David to go there. Every location in Genesis is revisited in the post-conquest of Israel. In the book of Judges especially. Places like Beersheba, Bethel, Shechem, Mizpah of Gilead, Succoth, Penuel, Bethlehem, etc are introduced in Genesis and revisited in the post-conquest of Joshua/the Israelites. Interestingly enough, similar things happen at these certain locations as they did before/after the conquest.

Comment: this is a very interesting answer. How did you figure out that all of the location in Genesis were revisited?